# Handler.postDelayed never gets triggered (Java - Android)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, android-looper

I have been trying to find for some time why my Handler does not trigger the events at all but I had no luck in finding it. I will post the entire class and hopefully someone notices a stupid mistake or something.

The class is only managing the lifespan of some sockets (I am doing that because the android devices seem to be very moody when it comes to reopening ports shortly after closing them). The class is a singleton as I want to have awareness of what ports I use everywhere.

```
package com.ltd.jeefo.alex.routeassistant.wifi.sync.utils;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.ltd.jeefo.alex.routeassistant.logging.ILog;
import com.ltd.jeefo.alex.routeassistant.logging.ScopedLogger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by Alex on 16/02/18.
 */

public class SocketsManager {
    private static final SocketsManager ourInstance = new SocketsManager();
    private static final Handler handler = new Handler();

    public static SocketsManager getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    @SuppressLint("UseSparseArrays")
    private static final HashMap<Integer, ManagedServerSocket> serverSockets = new HashMap<>();

    private SocketsManager() {
    }

    /**
     * Method used for obtaining the server socket for a given port
     * @param port the port where we want the socket to be opened
     * @return the server socket to be used or null if we couldn't start a server socket at that port
     */
    public ManagedServerSocket getSocketAtPort(final int port) {
        ManagedServerSocket managedServerSocket;
        if (serverSockets.containsKey(port)) {
            managedServerSocket = serverSockets.get(port);
        } else {
            managedServerSocket = new ManagedServerSocket(port, handler);
            serverSockets.put(port, managedServerSocket);
        }

        return managedServerSocket;
    }

    /**
     * Closes all the sockets after some delay
     *
     * @param msDelay the delay in milliseconds
     */
    public void closeAllSocketsAfterDelay(final long msDelay) {
        for (final ManagedServerSocket managedSocket : serverSockets.values()) {
            managedSocket.RequestSocketClosingAfterDelay(msDelay);
        }
    }

    enum ServerSocketStatus {
        OPEN_NOT_REQUESTED,
        OPEN_FAILED,
        OPENED, // there is always a close request started by default, just in case
        USER_CLOSE_REQUESTED,
        CLOSED
    }

    public class ManagedServerSocket {
        private final ILog logger;

        private final static long DEFAULT_CLOSING_TIME_MILLS = 3600000; // one hour
        private final static long DEFAULT_RETRY_TIME_MILLS = 15000; // 15 seconds
        private final Handler mHandler;
        private final int mPort;

        private ServerSocket mSocket;
        private SocketsManager.ServerSocketStatus serverSocketStatus;
        private Long closingTime;

        private Runnable defaultClosingRunnable;
        private Runnable explicitClosingRunnable;

        private ManagedServerSocket(final int port, final Handler handler) {
            this.mPort = port;
            this.mHandler = handler;
            logger = new ScopedLogger(null, ManagedServerSocket.class, "Port", Integer.toString(mPort));

            serverSocketStatus = SocketsManager.ServerSocketStatus.OPEN_NOT_REQUESTED;

            defaultClosingRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        logger.Warn("Server socket closing automatically at port %s after long delay",
                                Integer.toString(mPort));
                        mSocket.close();
                        serverSocketStatus = SocketsManager.ServerSocketStatus.CLOSED;
                        closingTime = new Date().getTime();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        logger.Error(e, "Failed to close server socket at port %s after delay", Integer.toString(mPort));
                    }
                }
            };

            explicitClosingRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        logger.Debug("Socket closing after delay");
                        mSocket.close();
                        serverSocketStatus = SocketsManager.ServerSocketStatus.CLOSED;
                        closingTime = new Date().getTime();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        logger.Error(e, "Failed to close server socket after delay");
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public void RequestSocketClosingAfterDelay(long delayMills) {
            logger.Debug("Close socket after delay %s ms", Long.toString(delayMills));
            switch (serverSocketStatus) {
                case OPEN_NOT_REQUESTED:
                    logger.Warn("Closing port that was never opened");
                    return;
                case OPEN_FAILED:
                    logger.Error("Cannot close a socket that failed to open");
                    return;
                case CLOSED:
                    logger.Warn("Cannot request closing an already closed socket");
                    return;
                case OPENED:
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(defaultClosingRunnable);
                    break;
                case USER_CLOSE_REQUESTED:
                    logger.Warn("Requested to close a socket that was already requested for closing");
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(explicitClosingRunnable);
                    break;
            }

            mHandler.postDelayed(explicitClosingRunnable, delayMills);
            serverSocketStatus = SocketsManager.ServerSocketStatus.USER_CLOSE_REQUESTED;
        }

        @Nullable
        private ServerSocket RequestSocketForUsage() {
            boolean socketIsOpened = true;
            switch (serverSocketStatus) {
                case USER_CLOSE_REQUESTED:
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(explicitClosingRunnable);
                    break;
                case OPENED:
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(defaultClosingRunnable);
                    break;
                case CLOSED:
                case OPEN_FAILED:
                case OPEN_NOT_REQUESTED:
                    socketIsOpened = tryOpenServerSocket();
                    break;
            }

            if (!socketIsOpened) {
                serverSocketStatus = SocketsManager.ServerSocketStatus.OPEN_FAILED;
                logger.Error("Failed to open the socket server and return it");
                return null;
            }

            // Add back the default closing handler now
            mHandler.postDelayed(defaultClosingRunnable, DEFAULT_CLOSING_TIME_MILLS);
            serverSocketStatus = SocketsManager.ServerSocketStatus.OPENED;
            return mSocket;
        }

        @Nullable
        public Socket accept() throws IOException {
            ServerSocket socket = RequestSocketForUsage();
            if (socket != null) {
                return socket.accept();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public SocketsManager.ServerSocketStatus getStatus() {
            return serverSocketStatus;
        }

        private boolean tryOpenServerSocket() {
            int attempt = 0;
            do {
                ++attempt;
                try {
                    this.mSocket = new ServerSocket(mPort);
                    break;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.Warn(e, "Failed to start ServerSocket on attempt: %s", Integer.toString(attempt));
                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            wait(DEFAULT_RETRY_TIME_MILLS);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                            logger.Error("Retry wait() interrupted");
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (attempt < 6);

            if (this.mSocket == null) {
                logger.Error("Failed to start ServerSocket");
                return false;
            } else {
                logger.Info("ServerSocket started");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**----------------------------------------- LATER EDIT -----------------------------------------**

I am always triggering the getSocketAtPort() method inside asyncTasks which seems to be part of the problem.

I now opened a socket (using getSocketAtPort()) inside an activity (inside onCreate()) before calling it in asyncTasks. When I do that all the handlers start working (including the ones requested inside the asyncTask). My guess is that the problem has something to do with threading.

Comment: So you've waited for an hour and your defaultClosingRunnable was not run ? Are you sure it hasn't been removed from the Handler ?

Comment: I am neither that stupid nor that patient. I obviously modified those values while I was testing it. I edited now the question with some extra info that I noticed.

Comment: you can try `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())` to guarantee the `Runnable` objects being called on the main thread.

Comment: is blocking `ManagedServerSocket#accept()` method called in your code?

Comment: @pskink Yes, it is. As I said, if I start a socket listener in the activity first, everything works fine (data is received and everything). P.S. that works fine even with the problem. as in I can receive data there. the only problem is that the automated port closing logic wouldn't trigger (as it is inside the handler that never starts the runnable)

Comment: if your thread is blocked by `accept` call then no wonder that no `Runnable`s are dispatched by a current `Looper` - use `HandlerThread` to post them in different thread

Comment: @pskink That makes complete sense now that I am thinking of it. If you post it as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks